# Why does indexing with a single character index work on a data frame but not a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, subset

In data frames, `[`-indexing can be performed using a single character. E.g. `mtcars["mpg"]`.

On the other hand, trying the same on a matrix, results in `NA`, e.g.

```
m = cbind(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)
m["A"]
# NA
```

...implying that this is somehow an invalid way to subset a matrix.

Is this normal R behavior? If so, where is it documented?

Comment: see  [subsetting](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/subsetting.html)  from Advanced R. this paragraph explains what you are looking for

Comment: @Elia That doesn't appear to be a link to a particular paragraph. If you want to quote the relevant part(s) and submit them as an answer, then I'd be happy to read that. It probably won't answer my "where is it documented" question, but it would still be nice to have.

Comment: Sorry, I mean chapter not paragraph. However, Advanced R from Hadley is one of the best sources for learning R from its basis. I think in this chapter you will find a lot of useful information on subsetting for vectors, matrices, and lists, and it explains the differences between the three different subsetting operators. The answer from @Gregor Thomas touch some of these arguments

Comment: `?Extract` matrix entry says: "An empty index (a comma separated blank) indicates that all entries in that dimension are selected."  and "Indexing via a character matrix with **one column per dimension**  ...". list like structure section has different rules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behaviour is documented in `?"["`, section "Matrices and arrays":

> Matrices and arrays are vectors with a dimension attribute and so
> all the vector forms of indexing can be used with a single index.

It means that if you use just a single index, the object to subset is treated as an object without dimensions and so if the index is a character vector, the method will look for the `names` attribute, which is absent in this case (try `names(m)` on your matrix to check this). What you did in the question is totally equivalent to `(c(1:5, 1:5))["A"]`. If you use a double index instead, the method will search for the `dimnames` attribute to subset. Even if confusing, a `matrix` may have both `names` and `dimnames`. Consider this:

```
m<-matrix(c(1:5,1:5), ncol = 2, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:5], LETTERS[1:2]))
names(m)<-LETTERS[1:10]
#check whether the attributes are set
str(m)
# int [1:5, 1:2] 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "A" "B"
# - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

We have set `rownames`, `colnames` and `names`. Let's subset it:

```
#a column
m[,"A"]
#A B C D E
#1 2 3 4 5

#a row
m["A",]
# A B 
#1 1

#an element
m["A"]
#A 
#1
```

Comment: This answer might benefit from showing how `m` prints out. What's going on when you're subsetting `m` might be easier to understand when the reader can see `m`.

Comment: Edited with the output of `str(m)`, which I think is more informative than a `print(m)`.

Answer (score 7):

`cbind()` creates a matrix, by default. `mtcars` is a data frame.

```
class(cbind(A = 1:5, B = 1:5))
# [1] "matrix" "array"

class(mtcars)
# [1] "data.frame"
```

Because data frames are built as `list`s of columns, `dataframe["column_name"]`, using one argument in `[`, defaults to treating the data frame as a `list`, allowing you to select columns, mostly the same as `dataframe[, "column_name"]`.

A `matrix` has no such `list` underpinnings, so if you use `[` with one argument, it doesn't assume you want columns. Use `matrix[, "column_name"]` to select columns from a matrix.

`cbind` is a bad way to create data frames from scratch. You can specify `cbind.data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)`, but it's simpler and clearer to use `data.frame(A = 1:5, B = 1:5)`. However, if you are adding multiple columns to an existing data frame then `cbind(my_data_frame, A = 1:5, B = 1:5)` is fine, and will result in a data frame as long as one of the arguments is *already* a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Two cases here,

```
m = cbind(A = 1:5, B = 11:15)
typeof(m)
"integer"
```

And

```
typeof(mtcars)
"list"
```

So reading is different. First case needs comma,

```
cbind(A = 1:5, B = 11:15)[,"A"]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I don't love `typeof` here - `x = c(A = 1L, B = 2L)` is a vector of type `integer`, but you don't need a comma for `x["A"]` to work. There's nothing about the `"integer"` type that suggests you would need a comma to subset it. What does matter is that it's a 2-dimensional array, aka a matrix, and OP wants to subset the 2nd dimension.